# Problem connecting the library to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, lib

This is my first time using libraries and I decided to try them on creating calendars. I have included the library `implementation("com.emc.thye:VerticalCalendar:1.0.4")`in build.gradle.kts(Module:app)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rebzg.png)

But when I try to create it in xml layout the error occurs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgqxM.png)

I also noticed that when I launch the application, a lot of errors appear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu0L6.png)

Here is the library I decided to use: https://github.com/emcthye/VerticalCalendar?tab=readme-ov-file

I tried to include other libraries, they all give almost similar errors

Comment: Did you sync your build.gradle file?

Comment: @tomerpacific Yes, I synchronized the files. Is it possible that the library is already old and is it supported?

Comment: [VerticalCalendar 1.0.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.emc.thye/VerticalCalendar/1.0.4)  is only available in the Maven JCenter repository which has been shut down a few years ago. Therefore just adding the implementation dependency will not work anymore. You can try to use the Git repo directy using https://jitpack.io for that you would have to adapt the artifact name.